# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database, I created the SQL database with phpmyadmin on localhost. My code seems correct and I have the JAR file added to eclipse. I have googled the error and found on here many topics that are the same but haven't been able to resolve the problem. Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class dbconnection {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:msql://localhost:3306/g52apr","root", "");
        java.sql.PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select * from std_details");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
        while (result.next()){
            System.out.println(result.getString(1) + " " + result.getString(2));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exact error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:3306/g52apr
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at dbconnection.main(dbconnection.java:10)
```

Comment: a quick browse of the internet indicates that you should change you connection string to `jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:3306/g52apr`

Comment: i did try that and no improvement i still get the error

Comment: Do you have sql server installed on the machine you're trying to run this code from?

Comment: I'm trying to run the code with eclipse like I say in message

Comment: also, i had the connection string wrong in my answer below. I just edited it to reflect the correct connection string. Please try that.

Comment: Right, I see that you are trying to run it from eclipse. That said, the SQL server driver still needs to be available to java.

Comment: You are using the wrong jar. You are loading a MySQL driver and try to connect to a SQL server database, that isn't going to work. Use the right driver.

Comment: Can we actually clarify that he is trying to connect to an SQL Server database? I know the question has the tag, but that really doesn't guarantee anything. He mentions using "phpmyadmin" to create the DB, and as far as I know (from just Googling it) that is for MySQL databases, not SQL Server.

Comment: which driver should i use then, I'm a bit confused what is the difference ?

Comment: @Tuytuy That depends on which RDBMS you're using, so which RDBMS are you using? MySQL? Microsoft SQL Server? Something else?

Comment: MySQL, i created the database using phpMyAdmin

Comment: You are missing a `y` in your connection string. Change `jdbc:msql...` to `jdbc:mysql...`. See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"jdbc:msql://localhost:3306/g52apr"
```

should be:

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/g52apr"
```

**Edited** Changed SQL Server reference to MySql

Comment: The question asker has clarified that they are trying to connect to a MySQL database, so the question was just incorrectly tagged. You'll probably want to edit or delete your answer to address that new information.

Comment: Easiest type of mistake to make. I've made that and similar mistakes dozens if not hundreds of times.